# Posgresql - jsonb object reduce without a subquery

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, postgresql-json

I have a `jsonb` column with permissions of users like this (this is a value of one record):

```
{
   "user_1":{
      "permissions":[
         "edit",
         "view"
      ]
   },
   "user_2":{
      "permissions":[

      ]
   },
   "user_3":{
      "permissions":[
         "view"
      ]
   }
}
```

What I want to achieve is to transform this jsonb object into a jsonb array of objects like this:

```
[
   {
      "login":"user_1",
      "permissions":[
         "edit",
         "view"
      ]
   },
   {
      "login":"user_2",
      "permissions":[

      ]
   },
   {
      "login":"user_3",
      "permissions":[
         "view"
      ]
   }
]
```

Just "move" login key to a separate field and index it as an array.

The question is:
**Is it possible it do it in PostgreSQL (version 10.x) without a subquery ?**

This is my version with a subquery:

```sql
SELECT jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('login', tbl.key, 'permissions', tbl.value->'permissions')), id FROM (
    SELECT (jsonb_each(permissions_tbl.permissions_obj)).*, id
    FROM (
        SELECT '{"user_1": {"permissions": ["edit", "view"]}, "user_2": {"permissions": []}, "user_3": {"permissions": ["view"]}}'::jsonb permissions_obj, 123 id
    ) as permissions_tbl

) as tbl GROUP BY id;
```

I used `jsonb_each`, `jsonb_build_object` and `jsonb_agg`. `id` is releated to `permissions_obj` containing multiple users and permissions. Any advice to impove the query is really welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Click: step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9c27b857b21ce90818338b8e00381d40)

```
SELECT
    jsonb_agg(                                  -- 4
        jsonb_build_object('login', key)        -- 2            
        || value                                -- 3
    )
FROM
    mytable,
    jsonb_each(mydata)                          -- 1
```

1. Expand the JSON object into one row per element. That creates two new columns: `key` (which are your `login`s) and `value` (which are your `permissions` objects)
2. Create a new JSON object for the `login`s
3. Add the `permissions` objects to the new JSON objects
4. Reaggregate them into a JSON array

Comment: Great answer @S-Man - thank you! Exactly what I was looking for :)